# How to send raw packets larger than MTU?

Tags: sockets

In the following code:

```
while (true)
{
    readfds = orig;
    activity = select(nfds, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (activity == -1)  // sockets closed
        break;
    CHECK(activity > 0, "");
    for (int i = 0; i < numSocks; i++)  // numSocks is equal to 2
        if (FD_ISSET(_sock[i], &readfds))
        {
            int len = recv(_sock[i], buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_TRUNC);
            CHECK(len > 0, "");
            CHECK(len <= sizeof(buf), "small size buffer");
            printf("%10d %d %d\n", ++packetNumber, i, len);
            CHECK(send(_sock[!i], buf, len, 0) != -1, "%s", strerror(errno));
        }
}
```

I'm going to forward everything I get from one NIC to another for both interfaces. I `recv` I've no problem with large (eg. 2700 bytes long) packets, but I get `Message too long` error in `send` for the same packets. `sizeof(buf)` is large enough (64k). Both sockets are of type RAW. OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

What's the problem and how can I solve it?

### Update

The following command:

```
sudo ethtool -K enp0s3 rx off tx off sg off tso off ufo off gso off gro off lro off rxvlan off txvlan off ntuple off rxhash off
```

resulted in the following output:

```
Cannot change udp-fragmentation-offload
Cannot change large-receive-offload
Cannot change tx-vlan-offload
Cannot change ntuple-filters
Cannot change receive-hashing
Actual changes:
tx-checksumming: off
    tx-checksum-ip-generic: off
scatter-gather: off
    tx-scatter-gather: off
rx-vlan-offload: off
tx-vlan-offload: off [fixed]
```

but solved the problem. :)

Now I'm going to find what options exactly should get turned off.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm reading it and will inform the result.

Comment: Yeah, it could solve the problem. Although I got the result I mentioned in the update to my question. Thx

Comment: Are these changes permanent? In another words, do I need to turn them off every time system reboots?

Comment: I found that the configuration is reset by reboot. I also found that turning only `gro` off is sufficient. It was by trial and effort. Maybe I've not to count on it and turn other settings off too?